# How can I duplicate the look of a comment area on the iOS setting page in a TableView?

Tags: xamarin, xamarin.forms, xamarin.forms-styles

I would like to add comments to my settings page. Something that looks like the comment area below "Ask to Join Networks" on the Settings > Wi-Fi page of the iOS Settings.

Can anyone suggest how I can do this and how I can make use of Dynamic Typing so that when the user changes the font size the comment area changes to match that in iOS settings?

Note that I am okay to use an iOS Renderer if needed. At this time I am just concerned with an iOS solution.

Thank you very much

Answer (score 1, accepted):

On iOS 11, the background color of a setting page is `#EAEAF1` and the text color within a non-control area is `#59595F`

So add a `Label` to a `ViewCell` but place it within another container so you can control the margin of the label otherwise your label text will be flush on the left side vs. vertically aligned to the setting controls.

Something like this will get your started:

```
<ViewCell>
    <StackLayout 
        Orientation="Horizontal"
        BackgroundColor="#EAEAF1">
        <Label
            Margin="15"
            TextColor="#59595F" 
            HorizontalOptions="CenterAndExpand"
            LineBreakMode="WordWrap" 
            Text="This is a multi-line custom ViewCell-based label, sdfsdfsdfsddf sdfsdf sdf sdf sdf sdf sd fsd fsd fsdf df" />
    </StackLayout>
</ViewCell>
```